# WP_Query - Adding "offset" posts to the end of the loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, offsets

I'm trying to create two queries.

In the first query, I will, for example, display 6 posts, in a given order.

In the second query, I want to display the *same* 6 posts, but "offset" the first 3 and then have those same 3 appear at the end.

For example, Query #1 would return:

1
2
3
4
5
6

Then, Query #2 would return:

4
5
6
1
2
3

Any ideas on how I might pull this off??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to have two queries, you can just reuse the same post data by resetting the current post position and running the loop again: `$wp_query->current_post = 2;`

you'd have to do this twice to achieve what you're asking, and stop it the second time at the third post.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will give this a try and report back!